# Downloading data from memory using STM32 cube programmer fails with error "Data read failed"

Tags: stm32

I am connected with a STM32 cube programmer to a chip and essentially want to dump all the memory into a file (Windows 10, device STM32H7xx, MCU, 2MB flash size). I tried this command

```
.\STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=swd -halt -u 0 500000 C:\Users\DALEX\Work\test.bin
```

but it failed with the following output:

```
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
                       STM32CubeProgrammer v2.13.0
      -------------------------------------------------------------------

ST-LINK SN  : 53FF71065056705420540981
ST-LINK FW  : V2J29S7
Board       : --
Voltage     : 3.22V
SWD freq    : 4000 KHz
Connect mode: Normal
Reset mode  : Software reset
Device ID   : 0x450
Revision ID : Rev V
Device name : STM32H7xx
Flash size  : 2 MBytes
Device type : MCU
Device CPU  : Cortex-M7/M4
BL Version  : 0x90

Core halted

UPLOADING ...
  File          : C:\Users\DALEX\Work\test.bin
  Size          : 500000 Bytes
  Address:      : 0x0
Read progress:
��������������������������������������������������Error: Data read failed
```

Anything I can try? Or a different command I could use?

P.S. Seems I only can download 65536 bytes. I cannot download more of that in one go?

But when I choose a different start address and try to download 65536 bytes, then I also get the same error again. Then I cannot even download 1 byte! Seems the controller only has 65536 byte size, but that is incorrect.

Option bytes:

```
OPTION BYTES BANK: 0

   Read Out Protection:

     RDP          : 0xAA (Level 0, no protection)

   BOR Level:

     BOR_LEV      : 0x0 (reset level is set to VBOR0)

   User Configuration:

     IWDG1_SW     : 0x1 (Independent watchdog is controlled by software)
     IWDG2_SW     : 0x1 (Independent watchdog is controlled by software)
     NRST_STOP_D1 : 0x1 (STOP mode on Domain 1 is entering without reset)
     NRST_STBY_D1 : 0x1 (STANDBY mode on Domain 1 is entering without reset)
     FZ_IWDG_STOP : 0x0 (Independent watchdog is freezed in STOP mode)
     FZ_IWDG_SDBY : 0x0 (Independent watchdog is freezed in STANDBY mode)
     BCM4         : 0x0 (CM4 boot disabled)
     BCM7         : 0x0 (CM7 boot disabled)
     NRST_STOP_D2 : 0x0 (STOP mode on Domain 2 is entering with reset)
     NRST_STBY_D2 : 0x0 (STANDBY mode on Domain 2 is entering with reset)
     SWAP_BANK    : 0x1 (after boot loading, user sectors swapped)
     IO_HSLV      : 0x0 (Product working in the full voltage range, I/O speed optimization at low-voltage disabled)

   Boot address Option Bytes:

     BOOT_CM7_ADD0: 0x800  (0x8000000)
     BOOT_CM7_ADD1: 0x1FF0  (0x1FF00000)
     BOOT_CM4_ADD0: 0x810  (0x8100000)
     BOOT_CM4_ADD1: 0x1000  (0x10000000)

   PCROP Protection:

     PROT_AREA_START1: 0xFF  (0x800FF00)
     PROT_AREA_END1: 0x0  (0x80000FF)
     DMEP1        : 0x0 (Flash Bank 1 PCROP zone is kept when RDP level regression (change from level 1 to 0) occurs)
     PROT_AREA_START2: 0xFF  (0x810FF00)
     PROT_AREA_END2: 0x0  (0x81000FF)
     DMEP2        : 0x0 (Flash Bank 2 PCROP zone is kept when RDP level regression (change from level 1 to 0) occurs)

   DTCM RAM Protection:

     ST_RAM_SIZE  : 0x0 (2 KB)

   Write Protection:

     nWRP0        : 0x0 (Write protection active on this sector)
     nWRP1        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP2        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP3        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP4        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP5        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP6        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP7        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP8        : 0x0 (Write protection active on this sector)
     nWRP9        : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP10       : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP11       : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP12       : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP13       : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP14       : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
     nWRP15       : 0x1 (Write protection not active on this sector)
```

Comment: It'd possible the chip is read protected. When you connect to the chip and hit read, can you see data for entire 2MB or partially ?

Comment: Seems I can read the entire chip via the GUI application ...

Comment: Ah wait, I can read the memory via the GUI application and then do 'save as ...'! That should work as well...